# How do I resolve database migration error due to changed migration filename?

Tags: python, django, database, deployment, database-migration

I'm still pretty new to Python as well as Django so I have a situation I'm not sure how to resolve.

Main issue is that on deploy of my code to dev, deployment fails, to stage or prod, it passes.

I worked on an issue where I had to drop some columns in a table in our app.
After making the changes, I deployed to dev and asked for a code review.
In code review, it was suggested I change the name of the migration file to something more descriptive rather than just leaving it 0018_auto_.

I made that change and deployed to dev and stage. Dev failed (when I expected it to succeed) because the new name was seen and django tried to drop columns that no longer exist. In stage, the name was never changed and the columns were dropped for the first time using that new name of the file.

So stage deploys just fine.

How do I resolve this error on dev so it recognizes this migration already took place?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the migration fails not because the filename changed, but because you already did the migration manually. You could put the columns back, or if you are sure you manually did the migration correctly you could --fake the migration or you could manually enter the migration into the django_migrations table or you could comment out the migration and then run it...

Comment: Thanks for that comment Jimmy, I’ve been reading about —fake but I’m still not sure how to use it. Can you enlighten me with an example or article with a code example? I think that is what I need. And that’s right, I migrated with the old file name on dev and then changed it. So, it did successfully migrate in dev already. I guess I can readd the columns but I wanted to see if there was an easier way first.

Comment: If the first migration ran successfully under the old filename then you will need to undo or fix that first. You can undo the migration by reversing it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations or you can just change the value stored in the django_migrations table

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I’ll give reversing a try tomorrow.

Comment: So the idea you gave me in the first comment was ultimately what I needed to do. On deployment to gitlab, I could not figure out how to run --fake using Django and Zappa. I visited AWS RDS as well but didn't have a way to edit the tables there (I am not well versed in AWS). In the end, I edited my latest migration file and instead of RemoveField, I added them all back and deployed to dev. After that, I edited the file again to remove along with updating the model and serializer and bam, things seem great now! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these were great answers and will no doubt help others now and in the future!

I tried all these answers but only one thing worked. The long way!

For full visibility (**this worked locally** and I understand --fake now in practice, thanks @brian-destura!):

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0017 --fake # Move to 17 without removing changes done by 18
python manage.py migrate myapp 0018 --fake # 18 is already applied, so just migrate with the new filename
```

In deployment through gitlab, our django / zappa app just didn't want to deploy successfully though (even with many different solutions tried).

In the end, the only way to fix the issue was to update the 0018 migration file to add back all those fields, rollback the changes in the models and serializers, and re-deploy to dev.

After that, revert all those changes including the migration file, and re-deploy again to dev.

There's probably some easier way to do this but with all those with more backend knowledge out for the holidays (I'm a front end originally with more backend knowledge/projects through the last year), I was very happy to resolve and release my changes.

Thanks to you guys for some things to try, ideas, and def knowledge I could use to create this, my own long winded solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that the only change done for `0018` was the file name, and that it is the last migration for your app, you can do:

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0017 --fake # Move to 17 without removing changes done by 18
python manage.py migrate myapp 0018 --fake # 18 is already applied, so just migrate with the new filename
```

This will keep the changes that are present in `0018`, and just apply the changes to the filename.

Comment: Thanks for this comment and explanation, this actually worked great for my local testing but when it came to using --fake on gitlab in dev, through django and zappa, it didn't work out and I couldn't figure it out using this method. I did succeed though, I'll post the answer above.

Comment: All good! I haven't used zappa for a while, but looking back at the [docs](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#django-management-commands) (and for our future reference), you should be able to execute this on your dev deployment with: `zappa manage dev migrate myapp 0017 --fake` and so on.

Comment: Yep, I tried that command and a few other permutations. Didn't work out in the gitlab.yml but I appreciate it. I'll add what worked for me at the bottom, basically the long way around

Answer (score 1):

Django constructs a table named `djang_migrations` that keeps track of the migrations that have been applied. If you later change the name of a migration file, then it will appear as if that migration did not run.

You can rename the migration in the `django_migrations` table of your development environment with:

```
UPDATE django_migrations
SET name = '0018_new_name'
WHERE app = '%%%name_of_the_app'
  AND name = '0018_auto_'
```

where *`0018_new_name`* is the new name of the migration file.

By updating this name, Django should now consider the new migration file as done.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, although this should work, I was not able to find the table :D I gotta wait for my backend buddy to come back from vacation and check where to access this table. We also use Django and Zappa so the set up isn't quite clear in all cases which is why i turned to you guys. Thanks for the help!